# Why flyway give error with COLLATE SQL queries?

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, flyway

I have a spring boot api which save messages in mySQL(version 5.6).Now the messages should support emojis also, so I am trying to update mySQL variables via flyway but it shows syntax error for all COLLATE keywords.

SQL query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

Or any

```
 ALTER TABLE/COLUMN query with COLLATE
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what's wrong and format your code properly?

Comment: sorry, I was in hurry, thanks @Delphi for formatting, @M,K will edit,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is *probably* about `CHARACTER SET` (the encoding of characters), not about `COLLATION` (the ordering of characters within the character set).

If your columns are currently `CHARACTER SET utf8`,

```
ALTER TABLE foo CONVERT TO utf8mb4;
```

If the columns are already utf8mb4, then why do you that *collation* (`utf8mb4_unicode_ci`), it does not handle Emoji gracefully.  It would be better to use `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.